# cinnamon-core, Nemo does not show the sharing tab. There is no nemo-share

Tags: samba, filemanager, cinnamon, nemo

I have installed Linux Mint 18.04, and Ubuntu 18.04 + Cinnamon. On Linux Mint, Nemo shows a much better context menu and the file property dialogue box has "Share". On Ubuntu + Cinnamon, Nemo shows simpler a context menu, and the "Share" tab is missing.

I have searched the web, and the answer was installing "nemo-share", but there was no such thing on Ubuntu. I have seen [this page](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo), and added `ppa:webupd8team/nemo`. Why can't I find nemo-share? The versions of both Nemo were exactly the same: 3.6.5.

[image]
[image]

PS: It seems that the update failed.

```
sudo apt update
...
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/nemo/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/nemo/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/nemo/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

When I searched Google for "nemo ubuntu", there were two repositories, one from WebUpd8 and one from NoobsLab. Both had the same error message when updating.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` after adding that ppa?  I just tested it and it allowed me to install `nemo-share` on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I was going to append this but, after posting this, I did "update" again and found that there was an error. It said that updating from the repository can't be done securely. I will add the details to the post.

Comment: Ah, technical details of that PPA it does not have 18.04 support yet for it.  Maybe see if you can contact the maintainers of that PPA.  Check https://launchpad.net/~noobslab for contact info.

Comment: If they are not supporting 18.04 yet, can I install it anyway with some hack? If it runs on Linux Mint 18.04, I think there is no reason it cannot run on Ubuntu 18.04. The reason I installed Ubuntu instead of Mint is that Mint came with too much unnecessary stuff and there was no "minimal installation" mode.

Comment: You could possibly try downloading the source files on a supported release them copy to 18.04 and build it from there.

Comment: As of 2021-06-03, I am still missing a `nemo-share` package in Ubuntu. It seems that *nemo* has no sharing capabilities in Ubuntu :-\

Comment: I don't know if it works in 2023, but I'd rather not add an unknown (to me) PPA to achieve this basic task.